# Admin cannot publish

Tags: admin, capabilities, permissions

When I logged in on my site this morning I noticed that my user can’t publish anything. I am administrator and the only user on the site.

On Posts and Pages instead of “Publish” I have the “Submit for review” button and if I click on it the page is blank and displays “Sorry you are not allowed to modify this post”.

I have the same issue with all my plugins disabled and even after cache reset.

Can you help me?

Edit: Thanks for the answers i finally managed to fix everything

I found the answer ! After wandering on the Internets I found this page : https://wpindexfixer.tools.managedwphosting.nl/wpindexfixer/

So here is what I gave SQL:

```
    DELETE FROM wp_users WHERE ID = 0;
ALTER TABLE wp_users ADD PRIMARY KEY  (ID);
ALTER TABLE wp_users ADD KEY user_login_key (user_login);
ALTER TABLE wp_users ADD KEY user_nicename (user_nicename);
ALTER TABLE wp_users ADD KEY user_email (user_email);
ALTER TABLE wp_users MODIFY ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;

DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE umeta_id = 0;
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD PRIMARY KEY  (umeta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD KEY user_id (user_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD KEY meta_key (meta_key(191));
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta MODIFY umeta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;

DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 0;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD PRIMARY KEY  (ID);
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD KEY post_name (post_name(191));
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD KEY type_status_date (post_type,post_status,post_date,ID);
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD KEY post_parent (post_parent);
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD KEY post_author (post_author);
ALTER TABLE wp_posts MODIFY ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;

DELETE FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_ID = 0;
ALTER TABLE wp_comments ADD PRIMARY KEY  (comment_ID);
ALTER TABLE wp_comments ADD KEY comment_post_ID (comment_post_ID);
ALTER TABLE wp_comments ADD KEY comment_approved_date_gmt (comment_approved,comment_date_gmt);
ALTER TABLE wp_comments ADD KEY comment_date_gmt (comment_date_gmt);
ALTER TABLE wp_comments ADD KEY comment_parent (comment_parent);
ALTER TABLE wp_comments ADD KEY comment_author_email (comment_author_email(10));
ALTER TABLE wp_comments MODIFY comment_ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;


DELETE FROM wp_links WHERE link_id = 0;
ALTER TABLE wp_links ADD PRIMARY KEY  (link_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_links ADD KEY link_visible (link_visible);
ALTER TABLE wp_links MODIFY link_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;

DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 0;
ALTER TABLE wp_options ADD PRIMARY KEY  (option_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_options ADD UNIQUE KEY option_name (option_name);
ALTER TABLE wp_options MODIFY option_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;


DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_id = 0;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY  (meta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD KEY post_id (post_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD KEY meta_key (meta_key(191));
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta MODIFY meta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;


DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id = 0;
ALTER TABLE wp_terms ADD PRIMARY KEY  (term_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_terms ADD KEY slug (slug(191));
ALTER TABLE wp_terms ADD KEY name (name(191));
ALTER TABLE wp_terms MODIFY term_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;


DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 0;
ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy ADD PRIMARY KEY  (term_taxonomy_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy ADD UNIQUE KEY term_id_taxonomy (term_id,taxonomy);
ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy ADD KEY taxonomy (taxonomy);
ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy MODIFY term_taxonomy_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;


DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id = 0;
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 0;
ALTER TABLE wp_term_relationships ADD PRIMARY KEY  (object_id,term_taxonomy_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_term_relationships ADD KEY term_taxonomy_id (term_taxonomy_id);


DELETE FROM wp_termmeta WHERE meta_id = 0;
ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY  (meta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta ADD KEY term_id (term_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta ADD KEY meta_key (meta_key(191));
ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta MODIFY meta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;


DELETE FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE meta_id = 0;
ALTER TABLE wp_commentmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY  (meta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_commentmeta ADD KEY comment_id (comment_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_commentmeta ADD KEY meta_key (meta_key(191));
ALTER TABLE wp_commentmeta MODIFY meta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;
```

Despite an error on the primary key for table wp_usermeta this went well and everything is back to normal.

Comment: Have you checked the database to make sure you're still an admin?

Comment: You could try adding a user role management plugin to re-add missing capabilities, but it sounds like you may have been "demoted" somehow.

Comment: Hello @notarobot - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Please refrain from answering your question within the question itself. If you have found a solution, post it as a separate answer. Elaborating on why your solution works will also improve it's quality. Check out the "[answer]" page in our [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not use this (opening post) script as the scheme might have changed, use this https://wpindexfixer.tools.managedwphosting.nl/wpindexfixer/ up to date script

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain, by checking the wp_users table in your database (phpmyadmin), that you are still an administrator, then backup your database and then repair the wp_users and wp_posts tables. If that doesn't fix it, then look at the 're-add auto increment' paragraph in this article...

http://serversideguy.com/2018/01/31/wordpress-admin-is-seeing-submit-for-review-instead-of-publish-how-do-i-fix-that/

(Replace wp_ with whatever your table prefix is if it's not wp_)

Answer (score 0):

Install a role editor plugin and reset all permissions and capabilities.

Additionally, try to create a new admin user (if you can) and see if the problem persists when logged in as the new admin user.

Do you have a plugin which allows admins to review author/editor posts? If yes, that plugin might have messed up or corrupted some of the capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, my problem was when I installed the SSL certificate.
So I had to backup for without SSL.

When I restored, my admin user cannot publish posts, pages and upload imagens.
It's a problem with auto increment.

This 2 lines SQL solved:

-- change `YOURPREFIX_users` for your database prefix.

```
DELETE FROM YOURPREFIX_users WHERE ID = 0;
ALTER TABLE YOURPREFIX_users MODIFY ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;
```

My php version      5.6.35

WordPress version 5.6.1

Comment: You mean MySQL version 5.6?